# Removing apostrophe from string leaves 39

Tags: php, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to remove special characters from a string, preparing it for use in a URL. This is my code as of now:

```
public function __construct($string) {

    $remove = array("!", "'", '"', "(", ")", ";", "@", "&", "=", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");

    var_dump($string);
    $this->string = $string;
    $this->string = str_replace($remove, "", $this->string);
    //$this->string = preg_replace("/[\s_\-:+]+/", "-", strtolower($this->string));
    var_dump($this->string);

}
```

And this is what it outputs:

`string(16) "Today's Quiz" string(13) "Today39s Quiz"`

That makes no sense... At no point do I convert special characters or anything, so where does the 39 come from? I can't track it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown by the length of the string, your input is actually:

```
Today&#39;s Quiz
1234567890123456 -> 16 characters
```

Since you're trimming out `&` `#` and `;` characters, the result is the remaining `39`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that... Thank you. I thought var_dump would show the `&#39;`?

Comment: It does, but since it's being dumped into your browser, it's being parsed and rendered as the character it represents.

Comment: @Styphon: It does. Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` in the very beginning of your script and you should see the correct output.

Comment: I've added in a `htmlspecialchars_decode` with `ENT_QUOTES` and that solved my problem. Thanks :).